# how to rejected request missing header or wrong header in wso2

Tags: java, wso2

I have code in API WSO2 like this

```
<api context="/request" name="Request" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/Executionreport/{vtid}/{token}">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.vtid')" name="Vtid" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.token')" name="token" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <filter regex="1234" source="$ctx:token">
                <then>
                    <log>
                        <property name="sukses masuk token" value="0"/>
                    </log>
                    <sequence key="select_Execution_report"/>
                    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
                </then>
                <else/>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

so for this request I will use like this one

```
http://localhost:8280/request/Executionreport/1100/1234
```

so if the token is wrong I will replay this one

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
soapaction: urn:mediate
Host: localhost:8280
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
cache-control: 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 07:51:59 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Keep-Alive

{ "status":"401 Not Authenticated" }
```

i want to change the logic like the request is like
`http://localhost:8280/request/Executionreport/1100` with methods `GET` and have header `token=1234`
so if token wrong in header request wso2 will rejected  so status will be `HTTP/1.1 401 unauthorized`.

so my question how to create API methods `GET` and need header in WSO2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the incoming header as below.

```
<property name="Token" expression="get-property('token')" scope="transport" type="STRING" />
```

Based on that you can perform any action.

Comment: yes and for rejected request like send 401 status how to do that ?

Comment: <property expression="get-property('uri.var.vtid')" name="Vtid" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
           <log>
           <property name="Token" expression="get-property('token')" scope="transport" type="STRING" />
           </log> i have use this code and request like http://localhost:8280/request/Executionreport/1100 with header token=1234 but the value is null